# What are the different works for Film and Television based on the works of Philip K. Dick?

Tags: movie, tv, philip-k-dick

I recently finished watching the great series "Total Recall 2070" that was based on Philip K. Dick's universe.  Philip K. Dick's absurdist blendings of philosophical problems with Sci-Fi has a unique flavor, so I'm looking for any TV or film works based on his writings.

I've already seen "Total Recall" and "Blade Runner".

Comment: I've posted this in an answer to another question earlier but the following book might be of interest: "Counterfeit Worlds: Philip K. Dick on Film" by Brian J. Robb, a slightly disjointed book but definitely worth reading if you are a PKD fan!

Comment: Also IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001140/

Comment: Are list questions allowed here now? For a possible problem with "list of X" questions (even those with seemingly finite answers), see Paula's answer below. Also, the accepted answer is now rendered incomplete. Isn't this an argument for the closing of this question?

Comment: I'm not going to lie, this is probably the definition of a list question, so if it gets closed I won't begrudge anyone, not that I would anyway.  Nonetheless, I would argue that it is a very common popular question that requires only minimal maintenance, and both the community here and the sci-fi community at-large is generally enriched slightly by having this resource.  Also I should note that I asked this question back before we had finished defining what was on and off topic and at the time it was on-topic, make of that what you will.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have seen all of these other than Confessions d'un Barjo as it is French and really hard to find. You've already seen the really good ones, I'm afraid. Screamers and Imposter are good bad-movies, Next is fun. The rest are kinda blah.

- Blade Runner - Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep
- Screamers - Second Variety
- Total Recall - We Can Remember It For You Wholesale
- Confessions d'un Barjo - Confessions of a Crap Artist
- Imposter - Impostor
- Minority Report - The Minority Report
- Paycheck - Paycheck
- A Scanner Darkly - A Scanner Darkly
- Next - The Golden Man
- [The Adjustment Bureau](http://www.theadjustmentbureau.com/) - The Adjustment Team

**Soon To Come**

- [Valis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Free_Albemuth_%28film%29) - Radio Free Albemuth (Maybe, supposedly it has been done for a while and even shown; go find it, support it, and DEMAND they make the sequel! It would be based on the book Valis!!!)

**Unknown Status**

- [King of the Elves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_the_Elves) - King of the Elves

Total Recall, however, is about as loosely based a movie can get. There is a clinic that does what the Recall Clinic in the movie does, and a vague mention of about 1 paragraph for the rest of the film. The real story consists of a magic wand, aliens, and a promise to prevent the end of the world. Really. I know.

Comment: Since this was written, there has also been the [pilot episode](http://www.amazon.com/Man-High-Castle/dp/B00RSGFRY8/) of "The Man in the High Castle" for amazon, and amazon has [ordered a full series](http://io9.com/the-man-in-the-high-castle-gets-series-order-from-amaz-1686515015).

Comment: This answer is badly in need of a proper update; however in light of Electric Dreams: The World of Philip K. Dick, it would be silly to do so until that's either aired or been cancelled or whatever happens.

Comment: I'd recommend to also check out the David Cronenber's 1999 film "eXistenZ", which is loosely based or inspired by Dick's "The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch".
It's has some similarities of story and themes of going into a made up world (using a drug in the book and the console pod in the movie) so deep that when you leave it's hard to know if you've really left or are still in.
Plus, the characters in the movie (Ted and Allegra) in one scene are eating from a fast food called Perky Pat's Food, while the toy line in "The Three Stigmata" is called Perky Pat.

Comment: @mzywiol, for one, an answer addresses the question asked. Which is what are the different works based x authors writing. Your "answer" was a recommendation based off a similar work, which doesn't answer the question asked. Although not far off, unfortunately if you're using the words "recommend" that means you're likely not giving the answer to a question as it was not what the Author was looking for, hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the ones I know about:

- Blade Runner
- Minority Report
- Paycheck
- Imposter
- A Scanner Darkly
- Next

Answer (score 4):

Amazon has produced another series called *Electric Dreams*, which is an anthology-type series of episodes inspired by Dick.  We finished watching the first season on Amazon Prime.  The flavor is Philip K. Dick, but the episodes do not stick closely to the stories.  The end of "Autofac", for example, is very different from the story.

Comment: FWIW this series originally aired on Channel 4 in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Also *The Truman Show* is based on ***Time out of Joint*** and lately the series produced by Amazon; *[The Man in the High Castle](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Man-High-Castle/dp/B00RWYOWEM)*

Comment: Can you provide any evidence that the Truman Show was based on "Time out of Joint"? My understanding is that it was [inspired by several Twilight Zone episodes](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424053111904060604576574592522839126)

Comment: Yeah sure. if you remember, Time Out Of Joint surrounds a man in a “normal” daily life, with a usual life. He has his concerns and stuff but everything seems to be kind of usual. Suddenly he begins to realize something about his life is wrong, due to some details (the paper, the radio, etc). In order to discover what is wrong he tries to go further, but gets stopped again and again, until some paranoiac levels are reached.

Comment: At the end some moon-related things are shown that doesn't appear in The Truman Show and all, but the concept of someone being fooled in an artificial context is the same. (It's also said to be inspired by Plato's allegory of the cave).

Comment: I mean, it may be not as directly taken as Blade Runner, for example, but it has some inspiration taken by it, as Dark city drinks from Ubik.

Comment: The concept of "[man turns out to be living in a fake world](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlatonicCave)" is hardly a new one. I recall several stories with a similar trope.

Comment: Well, science fiction gets a lot of inspiration from early works, moreover in cinema. If you make a research, you would find there's a lot of articles that thinks those two works (which I like, both) are related in some tight way. I don't know exactly what was the screenwriter thinking about at the time he wrote it, or if they took some rights officially, if that's what you were referring to. In that case sorry to misunderstood.

Comment: @Paula What you say is entirely true. However, if we allow answers based on what might be based on PKD's works, based on similarities we find, the list might be limitless... which is not allowed here. Therefore, I suggest you limit your answer to what's proven to be based on PKD's works. Does *The Truman Show* officially list it as its inspiration?

Comment: @AndresF. Hi! well, apparently Warner Bros did bought the Time Out of Joint rights (I could only find a couple of links, here you go [link](http://www.philipkdickfans.com/mirror/websites/pkdweb/TIME%20OUT%20OF%20JOINT.HTM) [link](http://archive.wired.com/wired/archive/11.12/philip_pr.html) ) as I once read, and kept it for a while, in order to make a movie. Now, as far as I read even with this purchase, **Time Out of Joint** is not officially "based on" this work or at least it doesn't say it in the film.