# How true to the book is the Total Recall remake?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, philip-k-dick, total-recall-2012

In reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-the-different-works-for-film-and-television-based-on-the-works-of-phili) I learned that Total Recall was based on a book, and that the [original Total Recall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/?ref_=nv_sr_2) was not very much like the book at all.

Is the [rebooted Total Recall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386703/?ref_=nv_sr_1) truer to the book [We Can Remember It For You Wholesale](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6561374-we-can-remember-it-for-you-wholesale)?  Aside from the apparent difference that the movie is based on Earth instead of Mars, as pointed out in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47169/why-was-films-setting-changed-from-mars-to-earth-in-the-remake/47170#47170).

Comment: As they turned a short story into a full length movie one might expect a few deviations. But then again *Minority Report* and *Do Androids dream ...* make do as a very loose inspiration for the respective movies either.

Comment: @Ghanima I expect deviations in any book-to-movie conversion.  But many such projects stay at least mostly the same.  The Hunger Games, for instance, had some deviations but was basically the same. Divergent, on the other hand, was a very loose interpretation that was rarely true to the book at all.

Comment: @Dave not to mention how different "The Running Man" novel / film were :-D

Comment: On a side note, there's also an official novelization by Piers Anthony which sports a slightly different ending because he wrote it to match the first script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reboot is even less like the short story than the film with Schwarzenegger. All of this is fairly accurately explained on Wikipedia.

[Short story plot & Film adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Can_Remember_It_for_You_Wholesale#Plot_summary)

[Schwarzenegger film plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_%281990_film%29#Plot)

[Farrell film plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_%282012_film%29#Plot)